# Is there a way to know which type of java object has been send once it is deserialized?

Tags: java, serialization, udp, deserialization

There are methods to serialize or deserialize java objects...

Prepare bytes to send:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ObjectOutput out = null;
try {
  out = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);   
  out.writeObject(yourObject);
  out.flush();
  byte[] yourBytes = bos.toByteArray();
  bos.close();
} 
catch(Exception ex)
{

}
```

Create object from bytes:

```
ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(yourBytes);
ObjectInput in = null;
try 
{
    in = new ObjectInputStream(bis);
    Object o = in.readObject();
    if (in != null) 
    {
        in.close();
    } 


   } 
   catch (Exception ex) 
   {

   }
```

}

However, if someone wants to send different types of objects over the net is there a way to know which type of object has been sent. I guess there is the option to create a class and then serialize and deserialize it.

```
class SerialObject
{
   String type;
   Object object; 
}
```

Comment: Your `if (in != null) in.close` should be in a finally block. As it stands, `in.close()` isn't necessarily called, and `in != null` would always be true if executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the only way to know the type of object being sent is when you use the InstanceOf keyword in java . The java instanceof operator is used to test whether the object is an instance of the specified type (class or subclass or interface). The instanceof in java is also known as type comparison operator because it compares the instance with type. It returns either true or false.

```
class Demo{  
 public static void main(String args[]){  
 Demo s=new Demo();  
 System.out.println(s instanceof Demo);//true  
 }  
}
```

this code return true. just use the InstanceOf keyword .it will really help

Answer (score 1):

When you are Serializing you can store the types somewhere - map or cache or somewhere, but still not sure why you want that?

One option is to check with instanceof operator during deserialized . I am not sure if (why?)should there be more?

```
Object deserialized = in.readObject();

if (deserialized instanceof TypeAbdClass) {
  // do something with ..
} else if (deserialized instanceof SomethingElse) {
  ...
} else if (...) {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
Object.getClass()
```

This will return runtime class of an object

Refer java doc
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html